# WPF + DevExpress UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, devexpress

I would like to add to every control's binding the "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged".

I could realize that by just writing for every control:

```
Text/EditValue/Stuff="{Binding x, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

But if possible, I would like to avoid this approach, since it is just redundant xaml code I would have to write over and over again, instead of reusing once piece of code.

A style is not an option, because the object bindings differ from xaml to xaml.

Since DevExpress is in use, we make use of the ExtensionMethod

```
DevExpress.Mvvm.POCO.POCOViewModelExtensions.RaisePropertiesChanged(this);
```

But the problem here: Imagine editing a TextEdit (Clicking into the TextEdit, typing stuff) and while the cursor is still in the TextEdit field, call the extension method mentioned above. The TextEdit's EditValue will be reset to the old value, since the PropertyChanged didn't call before.

Is there any way to modify application wide all binding behaviour at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to modify application wide all binding behaviour at once?

No, different dependency properties have different default values for the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property, but you could create a custom binding markup extension:

```
public class PropertyChangedBinding : Binding
{
    public PropertyChangedBinding()
        :base()
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }

    public PropertyChangedBinding(string path)
        : base(path)
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

...and replace `{Binding}` with your custom binding across all your XAML files:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:PropertyChangedBinding x}" />
```